# Javascript/Jquery quote and double quotes escaping

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

A simple jquery line of code:

```
if ($j('#page2').length) {
    $j('#myPlaceHolder2').html('<button class=\"button3\" type=\"button\">Page II</button>');
}
```

This works perfectly fine. When I later create a span with id myPlaceHolder2, it displays the button.

Now I need to add an onclick event

```
 onclick=\"javascript:  $j('#'+openc).fadeOut('normal', function(){$j('#page2').fadeIn('slow')});openc='page2';\"
```

To the above .html, as follows

```
   $j('#myPlaceHolder2').html('<button class=\"button3\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"javascript:  $j('#'+openc).fadeOut('normal', function(){$j('#page2').fadeIn('slow')});openc='page2';\">Page II</button>');
```

And all hell breaks loose. I tried escaping each ' with \ but it breaks my site entirely for some reason. I'm not very familiar with javascript or jquery, only learning as I go, so any indication as to how to get this done would be helfpul, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it with jQuery:

```
$j('#myPlaceHolder2')
    .html('<button class=\"button3\" type=\"button\">Page II</button>')
    .find('.button3')
    .click(function () {
        $j('#'+openc).fadeOut('normal', function(){$j('#page2').fadeIn('slow')});openc='page2';
    });
```

Comment: Figured it out differently; just added the onclick event directly on my span!Duh! Thanks for your suggestion tho :)